# Change Default Font Size and Remove Unwanted Font Sizes in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor, wp-editor, fonts

I use TinyMCE Advance plugin. I've posted a question in the support forum of the the plugin but it seems that the author doesn't provide any support now. As you can see in the picture, the font size 12pt is the default font size. Every time I open the TinyMCE Advance editor, the size 12pt displays in the default state. How can I change the default size to 14pt and remove the size 8pt, 10pt,12pt?

I've done some research and it's was recommended that I go to:

```
wp-includes/js/tinymce/skin/wordpress/wp-content.css
```

and change the size in

```
body {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", "Bitstream Charter", Times, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #333;
    margin: 9px 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Old syntax */
}
```

In this case, I've changed it to 18pt, but it doesn't work. The thing is that the default 12pt size is still there. It just changes only when I click inside the text editor area; it will change from the 12pt (that displays as default) to 14pt. But actually when I type a text and publish, the result is the published text still displays 12pt size, not 14pt. So that means I have to select a font size 14pt in the drop-down list anyway in order to get the size 14pt.

[image]

Comment: the values for thsi dropdown are created by this file `wordpress\wp-includes\js\tinymce\tinymce.min.js` . Therefore the best approach I can think of if to create a js file to change those values and hook it after the admin loads.

Comment: No easy way to remove the unwanted sizes there directly in the tinymce.min.js?

Comment: You can edit the file and remove them, but you have to do that every time to Wordpress Core updates. The optimal solution is to create a plugin to include everything we speak of.

Comment: I see. But I cannot create that plugin. If you don't mind helping me with that. Supposed if I wish to remove them direct from there, which one I have to remove?

Comment: The one you don't want to be displayed in the dropdown

Comment: I am not sure which one. There're many

Comment: Hi, I have removed the unwanted font sizes from the file. The result is that those font sizes just disappear from the dropdown list BUT when I open Tinymce editor, the default 12pt is still there and again it will disapear when I click inside the text editor box. That means I have to select 14pt to get 14 size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a 2-parter. The first half will show you how to change the style inside TinyMCE when editing. The second half will show you how to remove things from the toolbar.

## Style TinyMCE

WordPress give us a neat little function called [`add_editor_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_editor_style/) which accepts an array of stylesheets, either by URL or relative paths. WordPress default themes usually take advantage of this function and can be seen in the latest [TwentySeventeen theme](https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/blob/master/functions.php#L97). First let's create a stylesheet. The name doesn't matter but the location does.

```
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

For simplicity we'll call this `editor-style.css` and save it in the theme:

```
/assets/css/editor-style.css
```

Next we need to tell WordPress to use our stylesheet so we'll open the themes `functions.php` file and add in:

```
/**
 * Theme setup functionality
 *
 * @return void
 */
function prefix_theme_setup() {

    // Relative path to the TinyMCE Stylesheet
    add_editor_style( array( 'assets/css/editor-style.css' ) );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'iqt_theme_setup' );
```

Some plugins could interfere with this such as page builders if they implement their own TinyMCE.

---

## Modify Toolbar

Next, we can use the [`tiny_mce_before_init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/tiny_mce_before_init/) [filter hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init) to modify the TinyMCE. In this case, all we need to do if override the font sizes. You can add the following function into your `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * Add Formats to TinyMCE
 * - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/tiny_mce_before_init/
 * - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init
 *
 * @param array $args   - Arguments used to initialize the tinyMCE
 *
 * @return array $args  - Modified arguments
 */
function prefix_tinymce_toolbar( $args ) {

    $args['fontsize_formats'] = "14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt";

    return $args;

}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'prefix_tinymce_toolbar' );
```

The `$args` array has an index that accepts a list of font sizes separated by spaces. You can change these to whatever you want, `px`, `em`, `rem` it doesn't matter, just that the list is separated by a space and is a valid `font-size` value.

Comment: Your code also works. But I skip the first one as I already use 14pt in the syle.css in my child theme.

Answer (score 0):

I use only this one. It Works for me. What is the different between this code and your code?

```
// Customize TinyMCE editor font sizes
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpex_mce_text_sizes' ) ) {
    function wpex_mce_text_sizes( $initArray ){
        $initArray['fontsize_formats'] = "14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt";
        return $initArray;
    }
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpex_mce_text_sizes' );
```

Comment: Well, the first half of my code allows you to globally change the default font size in the editor, for display. The second half of my code is pretty much the same as you have it above.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Answer, It work for me:

1. Look for `functions.php` in root of your themes directory inside `/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/`, open it up and add one line after `php` tag.

   add_editor_style('custom-editor-style.css');
2. In the same directory, create a file called `custom-editor-style.css` with below lines in it

   ```
   @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
   * { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;}
   ```

Go ahead, clear your browsers cache and this is what you’ll see.

Refer link: https://blog.phi9.com/wordpress-editor-and-its-font/